# how to change xlim and ylim on a Taylor diagram in r

Tags: r, plotrix

I'm new to R and basically teaching myself programming.
I am struggling to increase the scale of a Taylor Diagram.
I have been at it for hours,

I tried.

```
# display the diagram with the better model
oldpar <- taylor.diagram(obst, MOHCREMO2015, ref.sd = TRUE,
                         grad.corr.lines = c(-0.2,-0.4,-0.6,-0.8,-0.9,-0.95,-0.975,
                                             -0.99,-1,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.95,0.975,0.99,1),
                         col = "darkgreen", pch = 3, show.gamma = TRUE,
                         xlab = "", ylab = "Standard Deviation",
                         main = "Swallendam", 
                         ylim = c(0,6),xlim = c(0,6))
```

> Error in plot.default(0, xlim = c(0, maxsd * 1.1), ylim = c(0, maxsd *  :
> formal argument "xlim" matched by multiple actual arguments

I want to produce multiple diagrams with identical scales.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Package `plotrix` uses base graphics, not `ggplot2`. You cannot add ggplot functions `scale_*continuous`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the unfortunate answer in this case is that you can't change xlim/ylim with `plotrix::taylor.diagram()`, but perhaps you could make a modified version that you could specify yourself.

`xlim` and `ylim` are set internally to `maxsd * 1.1` where `maxsd` is 1.5x the maximum standard deviation for `ref` or `model`. While `...` is passed to `plot()` you can't specify xlim and ylim twice, which is why you get the error "formal argument "xlim" matched by multiple actual arguments"

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I ran Taylor.diagram and replaced all maxsd with 6s from the base code, Then defined it as a new function. And it worked 